# Javascript - disabling options on change to prevent duplicate selections in select dropdowns causing issues with .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of 3 select dropdowns. I want the user to only be able to select 1 unique option across each of these 3 dropdowns. To do this I am getting the value on change of any of the select dropdowns and then disabling that option across all of the select boxes. This is working fine here:

```js
$('.select-cont select').change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();

    $('select option[value="' + selection + '"]').attr('disabled',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-cont">
  <label>Select 1</label>
  <select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select 2</label>
  <select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select 3</label>
  <select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

However, I also want the user to be able to change their selection, and if they do, the previous option they had selected should no longer be disabled. For that, I am getting the current option on `click` of the `select` so that I can target it to remove the `disabled` attribute:

```js
var prevSelection;
$('.select-cont select').click(function() {
  // $(this).val(); doesn't work for some reason
  console.log($(this).val());
  // event.target.value does work so let's use that
  prevSelection = event.target.value;
}).change(function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();

  $('select option[value="' + prevSelection + '"]').attr('disabled',false);
  $('select option[value="' + selection + '"]').attr('disabled',true);
});

$('button').click(function() {
  // this returns null if the click/change function exists
  console.log($('#first').val());
});
```

```css
button {
  margin-top:3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-cont">
  <label>Select 1</label>
  <select id="first">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select 2</label>
  <select id="second">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select 3</label>
  <select id="third">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button>Click to log first selection</button>
```

This is presenting two issues, both seem to have to do with `.val()` The first issue is that if I try to log `$(this).val()` within the `click` function, it returns `null`. If I instead use `event.target.value` then it correctly returns my previously selected option.

The other issue is that when I later try to get the values from the select boxes(on button click in the example) using `$(element).val()` also returns `null`. But if I remove the `click`/`change` function, then `.val()` correctly returns the selected value when I click the button. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: When you disable a `select` element, I think the expected value for it should be `null`. Did you try to look for the selected Option? `console.log($('#first > option:selected').val());`

Comment: @Twisty ahhh that makes sense. using `$('#first > option:selected').val()` does appear to work, thank you for that!